# Ubuntu SDK & QT Creator crash on start with error 'Failed to create OpenGL context'

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, opengl

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04, and followed the instructions for installing the Ubuntu SDK located here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/

On launching the SDK (or QT Creator), I receive the following error:

Welcome Mode Error:

> Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0,options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile 0).

In case it was related to me having an NVidia card, I tried switching over to the proprietary NVidia drivers, but am still receiving the error.

I found a post where somebody suggested that a fix for this in QT Creator is to go into the 'help > about plugins' menu in the application and disable the welcome screen, however both QT creator and the Ubuntu SDK hang before I can get to the option through the GUI.

Since I can't get that fix to work, and the official documentation just assumes everything works, I'm somewhat at a loss. If anybody could suggest anything to check, or any packages I need to install that weren't in the documentation, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but I am using Qt Creator with ssh X11 forwarding . I hope that my solution will help those that try to run the program locally and those try remotely.

The solution:

- launch Creator (in my case on Linux, with the exec being <qt_install_dir>/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator) with the following parameters:

  -noload Welcome -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler
- it may give you an error about not finding <qt_install_dir>/qtcreator; Ignore it and press OK
- go to Help->About Plugins...  and uncheck "Qt Creator->Welcome" (I also deactivated QmlDesigner and QmlProfiler)
- exit Creator and start it normally without any command line arguments

  This may work on Windows too. If anyone has tried it, please let us know.